# Map simple object to destination with multiple child objects

Tags: c#, automapper

Given following classes get an error as shown below.

```
   public class CPRequest
    {
        public ChannelType? ChannelType { get; set; }
        public bool IsJoint { get; set; }
        public int RiskTier { get; set; }
    }

public class CPGR
    {
        public CPGR();
        public AppSumm AppSumm { get; set; }
        public LS LS { get; set; }
    }

public class AppSumm
{
    public AppSumm();
    public int RiskTier { get; set; }
    public bool IsJoint { get; set; }
}




            
public class LS
{
   public Channel Channel { get; set; }
}
    
        
public class Channel
{
    public Channel();
    public ChannelType ChannelType { get; set; }
    public string ChannelCode { get; set; }
    public List<string> ChannelGroupCodes { get; set; }
}

public class MapperProfile
{
    public MapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CPRequest, Channel>()
        .ForMember(d => d.ChannelType, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.ChannelType));

        CreateMap<CPRequest, LS>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Channel, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.ChannelType))
        .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());

        CreateMap<CPRequest, AppSumm>()
        .ForMember(d => d.RiskTier, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.RiskTier))
        .ForMember(d => d.IsJoint, opt => opt.MapFrom(s=>s.IsJoint))
        .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());

        CreateMap<CPRequest, CPGR>()
        .ForMember(d => d.AppSumm, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s))
        // .ForMember(d=>d.LS,opt=>opt.MapFrom(s=>s))
        .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore())
        ;
    }

}
```

Usage:
var req = _mapper.Map(request);
Error:
Error mapping types.
Mapping types:

CPRequest -> CPGR
CPRequest -> CPGR

Type Map configuration:
CPRequest -> CPGR
CPRequest -> CPGR
Destination Member:
LS

How to use C# and Automapper to map properties from CPRequest onto CPGR

1. Map IsJoint to AppSumm.IsJoint
2. Map RiskTier to AppSumm.RiskTier
3. Map ChannelType to LS.LS

Comment: If you haven't already read the docs and tried configuring AutoMapper yourself, I'd start there. If you have, please post what you've tried and the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: Update the Mapperprofile class and error I experience when I uncomment the line// .ForMember(d=>d.LS,opt=>opt.MapFrom(s=>s))